# Comma operator in TypeScript JSX expressions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, stackblitz

An expression in this component

```
const App = props => (<div>{console.log(props), JSON.stringify(props)}</div>);
```

results in

> error TS1005: '}' expected

error around comma operator. This can be seen in this [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ete2uw) which is `create-react-app` project that uses TypeScript as a transpiler.

While comma operator [works as intended in Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAggBwTAvDBAnECKoHwwAUAPACYCWAbngN6iQgA2ApgHSMgDmhm2EAlABoYAKQDKAeQByraBnJhO5AGYBPHlhz8AvsQD0FavwDcQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=) in similar situation.

Is it TypeScript or Babel JSX implementation that is wrong? What does JSX specification say? Is it a known issue? If this is TypeScript's fault, can it be fixed?

Comment: Logged a Babel issue - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8604

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh So it's TS that is closer to the specs. That's interesting. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was possible to make an expression with comma operator work as intended in both TypeScript and Babel JSX implementation with either extra parentheses:

```
{(console.log(props), JSON.stringify(props))}
```

Or if it is `console.log` call that is always falsy, logical OR short-circuit can be used:

```
{console.log(props) || JSON.stringify(props)}
```